# Short Open Tag and <?=

Tags: php

By one hand, I know the use of the Short Open Tag `<?`   in PHP is discouraged  for several reasons: only available if enabled in php.ini, for clarity and avoiding confusions...

By the other hand, I see that **from PHP 5.4.0 and above, `<?=`  is always available regardless of the short_open_tag ini setting**.

More about PHP tags [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php).

My question: 
Is `<?=` considered Short Open Tag? Should I avoid using it in my PHP coding? Or should I do the opposite and use it since is very useful and not affected by the 'discourage recomendation'?

*Edited for clarifying: `<?= ... ?>` is equivalent to `<?php echo ... ?>`*

Comment: Excuse me if I am missing something, but what benefit would <?= hold over <?php...? Bar two extra characters?

Comment: Personally i'd follow the best practice route and stick with `<?php echo ?>`. I can't really dispute it as everybody has their own opinion but mines habit more so and classed as best practice.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are PHP short tags acceptable to use?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use)

Comment: @Jethro Hazelhurst `<?=  ... ?>` is equivalent to `<?php echo ... ?>`, not to `<?php ... ?>`

Comment: Hmm, interesting!

Comment: `<?=` is no longer considered a short open tag. The reason why `<?` was discouraged was (I think) because it was ambiguous under some situations. `<?=` doesn't have the same issue. I personally use it a lot. Others don't because they worry it will suffer the same fate as `<?` . I think until we see a deprecation notice it should be fine.

Comment: @apokryfos It was/is ambiguous to `<?xml ... ?>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is no formal answer, I put together some of the comments, which -in my opinion- actually answer the question:

`<?=` is no longer considered a short open tag. The reason why `<?` was discouraged was because it was ambiguous under some situations, i.e `<?xml ... ?>` or other markup languages.